# Extension of ring by the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

All rings considered are associative. We say that the ring $R$ is an extension of the ring $I$ by the ring $T$ if $I\lhd R$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ and $R/I\cong T$. Is there a scientific article where relationship between the ring $R$ and $I$ are investigated if  $T=\mathbb{Z}$? In particular, I am interested what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for ring $I$ to every extension of $I$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative. It is easy to see that the commutativity of $I$ is a necessary but not a sufficient condition (example of non-commutative ring $R=\{\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\0 &a\end{array}\right]\colon a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ which is an extension of the commutative (with zero multiplication) ring $I=\{\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & b\\0 &0\end{array}\right]\colon b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ by the ring of integers $R/I\cong \mathbb{Z}$).

An extra (more general) problem: When the extension of commutative ring by a commutative ring is commutative? I will be very grateful for indicating the works in which you can read about these issues.

Comment: ($I$ can be unital as shown with $T=I=\Bbb{Z}, R=\Bbb{Z}^2$)

Comment: @reuns: but it would not be a unital *subring*.

Comment: I do not assume that a ring have the unity. So, for me any abelian grroup with zero multiplication is a good exaple of a ring.

Comment: You might want to say that (since you took the time to make sure we knew you wanted them to be associative); it is far less common to assume a ring is possibly nonassociative than to assume it is nonunital. If you feel the need to specify the former cannot happen, you should likewise let us know that the latter is allowed.